# Qt not a template type

Tags: c++, qt, ros

I am working with an old project on Qt 5.6.2 and ROS, when compiling with catkin_make I keep getting this error:

```
/home/user/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:152:37: error: ‘remove_cv’ in namespace ‘QtPrivate’ does not name a template type
     typedef typename QtPrivate::remove_cv<typename QtPrivate::remove_pointer<T>::type>::type ObjType;
/home/user/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:152:46: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
     typedef typename QtPrivate::remove_cv<typename QtPrivate::remove_pointer<T>::type>::type ObjType;
/home/user/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:153:65: error: ‘ObjType’ has not been declared
     return static_cast<T>(qt_qFindChild_helper(this, aName, ObjType::staticMetaObject, options));
```

But all those libraries and headers are from Qt itself, I've tried changing the CMakeList files, the configuration file (.pro), the .bashrc seems to have the environment variables set correctly and it even compiles within Qtcreator but not catkin_make from terminal. Any idea what could be causing this errors?

Comment: Could it be pulling in additional (conflicting) Qt headers from a different path?